# making a complex yaml from R

Tags: r, yaml, dataframe

I am trying to make yaml format file from R. I know there is a package for such a job, but its example is so simple and my object is a bit more tricky !!

so I would like to make something like the following but I don't know how should I shape it as R object (dataframe?!):

```
tree:
  format: newick
  translate: ./My_example-1.translation
  file: ./Xtol_example-1.tree
tracks:
  - class: colorstrip
    source: ./My_example-1.catdomain

    rel_height: 0.6
    title: Catalytic domain
  - class: colorstrip
    source: ./My_example-1.kingdom
    rel_height: 0.6
    title: Itsname
  - class: colorstrip
    source: ./My_example-1.temp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My short advice - don't use yaml with R.

(Editor's note: It appears that the problems documented here have since been fixed--see the comments.)

**Issue 1**

The yaml package in R seems to be unusable but the real issue seems to be with R. But then again, I hadn't bothered with yaml till I saw this question, so may be there are gaps in my understanding of the whole issue.

To successfully create the yaml in question, at some point, we'll have to have a vector of lists which is not a list (for *tracks*). I think there is no way to do that in R. As soon as we add elements to a vector which are lists, the vector turns into a list. I guess a vector can only take elements of a fixed size (hence simplified operations, hence good performance and hence the abundance of advice to vectorize).

For simple atomic types like numeric, integer etc, I suppose the R interpreter already knows about their size (which is fixed). But if the element is a list, then that luxury is lost, and the vector is converted into a list so that it may deal with the varying sizes of the elements (lists).

Hence, there can not be a vector of lists which is not a list, and we have serious problems transforming data to and from yaml in R.

**Issue 2**

The R yaml package is poorly documented, and I can't figure out how does it solve the issue. I guessed that it might have used a convention to get around it. So what I tried to do was this (and this approach would also have solved your problem) - import the yaml as an R object and then try to convert that R object into yaml.

```
library("yaml")
z <- yaml.load(
"tree:
  format: newick
  translate: ./My_example-1.translation
  file: ./Xtol_example-1.tree
tracks:
  - class: colorstrip
    source: ./My_example-1.catdomain

    rel_height: 0.6
    title: Catalytic domain
  - class: colorstrip
    source: ./My_example-1.kingdom
    rel_height: 0.6
    title: Itsname
  - class: colorstrip
    source: ./My_example-1.temp")
names(z)
names(z$tracks)
y <- as.yaml(z)
```

as you would see, it doesn't work. I think you can save yourself a lot of pain by not trying to use yaml with R. You could consider using XML or something like that.

Comment: I contact to its developer and he fix the bug, now, with your method it works pretty well

Comment: Can you tell me how he fixed the bug? I would like to start using yaml myself if such headaches could be fixed.

Comment: oh, and you can do str(z) to see the structure of the object you produced from yaml. and again, can you please let us know what the author of the yaml package had to say about this?

Comment: I wish there was notification about comment below the answers ... Here is what he said me by email : Thanks for pointing that out to me. I've fixed it and have submitted a new version to CRAN. Hopefully it will be available in the next few days.

If you need the updated version right away, you can install it by following the instructions found here:

http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/YamlR#Installation

Comment: The example above now works fine. Perhaps this is a case of a package evolving but I have had no issues in 2012.